# Writing uint out as Hex not Int

Tags: c#, hex

In c# I have Error codes defined as

```
public const uint SOME_ERROR= 0x80000009;
```

I want to write the 0x80000009 to a text file, right now I am trying

```
 private static uint ErrorCode;
 ErrorCode = SomeMethod();
 string message = "Error: {0}.";
 message = string.Format(message, ErrorCode);
```

But that writes it out as a int such as "2147483656" how can I get it to write out as the hex to a text file?

Comment: `ToString("x8")` or `Format("{0:x8}")` uppercase `X` if you want uppercase hex characters.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `X` format specifier to output `uint` as hexadecimal.

So in your case:

```
String.Format(message, ErrorCode.ToString("X"));
```

Or

```
string message = "Error: {0:X}."; // format supports format specifier after colon
String.Format(message, ErrorCode);
```

In C# 6 and newer, you can also use string interpolation:

```
string message = $"Error: {ErrorCode:X}";
```

You might also want to use `X8` with 8 specifying the required number of characters so that all error codes are aligned. `uint` is 4 bytes large, each byte can be represented with 2 hex chars, therefore 8 hex chars for `uint` in total.

```
string message = $"Error: {ErrorCode:X8}";
```

See [Custom numeric format specifiers at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for further details.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to cast it. Simply do

```
message = string.Format(message, ErrorCode);
```

and if your method `SomeMethod()` is returning an `int` then you can convert your int to Hex like this:

```
message = string.Format(message, ErrorCode.ToString("X"));
```

Comment: I get the same number being output if I cast it or not, but yes the cast it useless.

Comment: @Lawtonj94:- If your method `SomeMethod()` is  returning the int then you can convert it to Hex using the `.ToString("X")`